# Regex to check if +,- or * are between two words in a string

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to check if there is a +,- or * between two words in a given String. Here are some examples:

```
"wordA + wordB" -> match
"wordA-wordB" -> match
"wordA wordB +" -> don't match
```

I tried `[\\w][\\+\\*\\-][\\w]` and `.[\\+\\*\\-].` but both don't work.
I hope it's sure what I want. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following regular expression:

```
"\\w+\\s*[-+*]\\s*\\w+"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the characters `+`,`*` which are present inside the character class. And you must escape `-` symbol when there is a preceding and following token exists.

```
^\w+\s*[+*-]\s*\w+$
```

Java regex would be,

```
^\\w+\\s*[+*-]\\s*\\w+$
```

You don't need to put the anchors while using the matches function.

**Example:**

```
String xxx = "\\w+\\s*[+*-]\\s*\\w+";
String x = "wordA + wordB";
if(x.matches(xxx)) {
        System.out.println("matches");
}
else {
           System.out.println("no match found ");
} // matches
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (?=\w+\s*[+\-*]+\s*\w+)^.*$
```

This works.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/1